# Spawning via gazebo_ros spawn_entity seems to not put /tf into namespace

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to spawn a robot dynamically via

```
ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -entity robot1 -x 0 -y 0 -z 0 -file ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle_pi/model.sdf -robot_namespace robot1
```

but when I do so, the /tf topic seems to be outside of the namespace. I did an echo of it with 2 robots running, but I could not distinguish data from the header of the messages.

Many documentation and tutorials only cover the general purpose, but I was not able to get any information wether /tf should be /robot1/tf so far.
Do you know if this is ok, or how I can remap etc.?

Edit:
Because its the same .sdf file, and /tf only transforms relations for the robots parts, this could be ok, right?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405712/spawning-via-gazebo_ros-spawn_entity-seems-to-not-put-/tf-into-namespace/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2022-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should look similar to this:

- In your launch files:

  `remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'), ('/tf_static', 'tf_static')]`
- and then in each of your nodes using `/tf`:

  ```
    Node(
        package='your_package',
        executable='your_package_executable',
        namespace=namespace,
        parameters=[parameters],
        remappings=remappings
    ),
  ```
- in your `urdf.xacro` you should have:

`<xacro:property name="robot_namespace" value="/$(arg namespace)"/>`

- in your YAML config files for e.g. Nav2 and in Python launchers - use `from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression, Command, TextSubstitution` and `from nav2_common.launch import ReplaceString, RewrittenYaml`, something like:

`odom_topic: /namespace/odom` etc. in YAML and `namespaced_params= ReplaceString(source_file=param_dir, replacements={"/namespace":("/",namespace)})` in Python launch files.

I used it to distinguish themes, services and actions for two and more robots in ROS2 Gazebo simulation. It works ok, so I think such a thing should be at least acceptable :)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1